# What's the difference in these ways of determining uploaded file size in PHP?

Tags: php

I came across this piece of code where programmer determines uploaded file size like this:

```
$file_size = @filesize($_FILES[$upload_name]["tmp_name"]);
```

AFAIK one can simply do:

```
$_FILES[$upload_name]["size"];
```

Are there reasons to use filesize() function over reading file size from $_FILES array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$_FILES[$upload_name]["size"]
```

This is populated for you by PHP after receiving the uploaded file.

```
$file_size = @filesize($_FILES[$upload_name]["tmp_name"]);
```

This is a wasteful method that goes out and gets the file size from the drive, even though it's already populated inside `$_FILES[$upload_name]["size"]`.

Comment: yeah. that was my though. just wanted to make sure there wasn't anything more to it that I wasn't aware of. thanks!

Comment: Is it really calculated by PHP or by Apache?